# Cómo filtro escribiendo el id con nodejs y express mediante endpoint get y peticion query?

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, get, endpoint

Eso es lo que tengo(mal) Usar restructuración

```
**.get("/user/:id", (req, res) => {
        const { id } = req.data;
        res.json({
            msg: "Usuario filtrado por id",
            body: `Hola ${id.data}`,
        });
    })**
```

Tengo 10 datos en un  archivo .json guardato en una constanta llamada data y su estructura es:
**

```
{
      "id": 3,
      "first_name": "VEVAY",
      "last_name": "Leivers",
      "email": "vleivers2@google.es"
    },
```

**

```
**
```

path "users-query" debe permitir realizar consultas al servidor mediante querys, la query que se puede enviar es "id" de tipo Number y el endpoint retornara un array con un solo objeto json (el objeto completo) que corresponda al "id". Si la query no es enviada deberá retornar todos los datos del json.

debo trabajar con estos datos de .json

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

Primero que todo `const { id } = req.data;` está mal debe ser `const { id } = req.params;` despues tendrias que verificar que id sea un numero, tal vez usar `let` en lugar de `const` te convendría mas.

Depronto esto te pueda dar una idea y llegues a lo que quieres hacer

```
.get("/user/:id", (req, res) => {
    const { id } = req.params;
    let dato = data.find(user => user.id === parseInt(id))
    if (dato) {
        return res.json({
            msg: "Usuario filtrado por id",
            // body: `Hola ${id.data}`,
            data: dato
        });
    } else {
        return res.json({
            msg: "Usuario filtrado por id",
            // body: `Hola ${id.data}`,
            data: data
        });
    }
})
```